# PayPal REST API App secret key not displaying in sandbox mode

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have been unable to retrieve the secret key for my REST API app in SANDBOX mode, although it is being displayed when in LIVE mode. I've tested with multiple browsers and on multiple terminals, and the SHOW button is just not responding in sandbox mode. I have also tried creating a new app, but the same issue persists with that too.

Has anyone else faced this issue? Could I have missed some step or requirement? The first app is an old one, created more than a year ago, and I was able to retrieve the secret key and test it sandbox mode then, and it is still working now.

Thank you for your kind attention.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same exact issue. This seems to be a Paypal problem, but here is a solution. Open up Internet Explorer and select your app from your Sandbox account. Once you are on the page with the API Credentials, open up Developer Tools. Choose the Debugger option, which will show you the source code. In the Find command in the Debugger (Cntrl+F), enter "secret selectable". You will find the secret key in the lines next to it. If this doesn't work, manually scroll through the code, and you will find your secret key next to the id tag "show-secret".